# Count Cycles in a time series

Tags: algorithm, time-series, pattern-recognition, waveform

I have a device that is sending continuously data. The data received changes the waveform in time. For example, for some hours I could receive data like this one:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g6thhtat1zx9rxm/1.PNG?dl=0

and after some time to begin receiving data like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u10vckcplev0qyh/2.JPG?dl=0

What do I need:

1. Count the number of cycles
2. If the waveform is changed, to detect and to count cycles based on the new pattern

In the first image the algorithm shall count: 4 cycles
In the second image the algorithm shall count: 3 cycles

Comment: You can try to look at some software for anomaly detection. I heard that [nupic](https://github.com/numenta/nupic) is a good tool for finding anomalies in time series data. Most likely that this tools doesn't solve your task directly, but has some instruments to solve related tasks. Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

Calculate [auto-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) for signal.

If period does exist, its value should correspond to the first non-zero peak in AC power spectrum. Divide full length by period value to get number of periods.

Don't forget to check whether determined period is real one (perhaps it is not so simple problem in signal processing)

Comment: thanks for helping. But the problem is that the period is variable. It could change in time. Not very much, 10-15%

Comment: In this case you might need to explore characteristic pitch events sequence, or even use some similarity search - much harder problem.